# Set start page for google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Browser start up going to a specific page even though I tried to changed it in settings and uninstalled the app which leads to.
It can be changed once but it changes to default after a while.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It means you have not cleared virus-like program. Use some special tool like CCleaner to clean all unwanted programs, reinstall chrome.

If that's not working, re-install Windows (or iOS, Linux or what ever OS you are using).

*Future tip*
Always double check all checkboxes/radio buttons when installing anything. Sometimes there is even `decline` button that must be clicked instead of checkbox/radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a tool to reset and recover your Chrome software from malicious software, addons, and extensions called the [Software Removal Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/srt/). You might give that a try.